# How to do script if key pressed then break out of infinity loop

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local whenthe = 1

while 3 == 3 do
    wait(0,2)
local v1 = {
    [1] = getrenv()._G.Pass, 
    [2] = "DashTeleport",
    [3] = "True"
}
local rem = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Remotes.SansMoves

rem:InvokeServer(v1) 
end
```

how to make this script break on "K" key pressed?
I looked for it but didn`t find any information on it

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/KeyCode) table, K key has code 107, and we can insert the check right into the loop and break it if the key is down:

```lua
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
while 3 == 3 do
    wait(0.2)
    local kHeld = UserInputService:IsKeyDown(107)
    if kHeld then
        break
    end
end
```

Or maybe better not to use infinite conditions, if you actually have a condition, like this:

```lua
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local kHeld
while not kHeld do
    wait(0.2)
    kHeld = UserInputService:IsKeyDown(107)
end
```